# Calculating execution time of my program

Tags: time, execution

So in my image processing project, I'm currently using gettickcount() to calculate the average time it takes for each frame to be processed. However, for the sake of speed, I chose to process every other frame. Theoretically, the program should run faster and it does. However, the values I'm getting from gettickcount remain the same. Which leads me to believe that the gettickcount function is still counting the ticks of the nonprocessed images of the program.

```
while(capture.grab())
{
    int64 t = getTickCount();

    if(count == 0) //count is each image number. this segment processes the first image
    {

    }

    if(count % 2 == 1) //processes every other image
    {

    }
}
```

Does the getTickCount function still count the ticks from the if(count % 2 == 1) even if it isn't employed?

thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you're on [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using C++. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @Jordy - Are you absolutely sure about that? Time for a coffee?

Comment: @Zec yes, the modulo operator returns the remainder after division. 0 / 2 = 0. So the remainder is 0.

Comment: @Jordy - I totally agree with you. So, substituting "count" with 0, we have the expressions "0 == 0" and "0 % 2 == 1". Only one of these is true (hint: it's not the one with the modulus operator). Only one if statement is passed. Also, thanks for cleaning up my code sample. That was lazy of me and I just bagged someone else for being lazy.

Comment: @Zec, you are totally right. I apologize, for some reason I kept reading == 0 (maybe because of the every other image comment, who is to say). And it is morning here, so perhaps it is time for a coffee ;). Sorry again. But still made more sense if it was == 0. That way the first and every other image would be processed.

Comment: Yeah, actually, that does make more sense. OP, pay attention. Unless you really like the odd-numbered images, make your life easier and do away with your "count == 0" statement and change the other to "count % 2 == 0". As Jordy says, this will handle processing the first image and every other in one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{

clock_t start = clock();

//write your code here, and this will calculate the execution time of the code...

clock_t ends = clock();

printf("run time: %.5f \n", ((double)(ends - 

start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Regardless of the value of "count", you are calling getTickCount on each pass of your while loop.

Try:

```
while(capture.grab())
{
    int64 t = 0;

    if(count == 0) //count is each image number. this segment processes the first image
    {
      t = getTickCount();
    }
    if(count % 2 == 1) //processes every other image
    {
      t = getTickCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add that the problem you're experiencing has as much to do with what you are later doing with "t" as it does your conditional that you've shared so far. What are you doing with "t"?